# How to Customize Sugar CRM export

Tags: php, export, sugarcrm

I have created custom module in Sugar CRM. The data / lead to this module is coming from web-forms. 
When I export leads of this module to the excel sheet then I get all data in excel sheet. But I don't want all data to be exported.

Any idea how to customize it ? I am using community version of Sugar CRM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a predefined entry for export. You need to override the export entryPoint and you can customize your export functionality.

export entryPoint directly hit on export.php at root directory

Create entry_point_registry.php file, add following code in it

```
$entry_point_registry['export'] = array('file' => 'your_file_path/export.php', 'auth' => true);
```

Comment: Can you please show me example of export entryPoint ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a overriding method create_export_query in your modules bean class (i.e. Leads.php or YourModule.php).

For example if you override the standard export function like this your export contains only the field "special_field_c".

```
function create_export_query(&$order_by, &$where){
        $custom_join = $this->custom_fields->getJOIN(true, true);
        $query = "SELECT
                        contacts_cstm.special_field_c as special ";

        if ($custom_join) {
            $query .= $custom_join['select'];
        }
        $query .= " FROM contacts 
                    LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm
                            ON contacts.id=contacts_cstm.id_c ";

        if ($custom_join) {
            $query .= $custom_join['join'];
        }
        $where_auto = " contacts.deleted=0 ";
        $query .= empty($where) ? "WHERE $where_auto" : "WHERE ($where) AND $where_auto";
        $query .= empty($order_by) ? "" : " ORDER BY " . $this->process_order_by($order_by, null);
        return $query;
```

}

Comment: Can you show me example for few fields ? i.e. code snippet of create_export_query method for few fields ? Thanks for your reply.